# Link to different locations depending on location of visitor

Tags: html

I have very simple HTML website with a button which takes you a specific book link on amazon.com. But I would now like to make the link a bit more sophisticated - if the visitor is from the UK, I would like the button to take them to the same book on amazon.co.uk. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Ok, ok, question edited.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is geolocation by IP address. This can be done on your server, but if you're using just HTML then you'll need to do it on the browser. So if you look for "IP geolocation javascript" then that will give you some companies that provide it.

If you don't want to pay any money then there are free services, but you have to ask yourself if they are reliable.

Sometimes these services get it wrong, so you may want to build in an override so someone can say "actually I am in the UK even though you think I'm not".